# Date Format for Mathematica

Tags: datetime, wolfram-mathematica, quantitative-finance

As I am trying to plot a few financial time series in Mathematica, I just ran into a problem illustrated in the figure below :

It seems the data are no longer dealt with after Year 2000

Is there a way to fix that ?

What would be the best format to export time series from Bloomberg or Excel to use them in Mathematic (Using version 8).

I do know about the FinancialData function. However, not knowing the exact symbols, it makes it extremely difficult to use Mathematica directly for this.

[image]

Comment: It is interesting to note that `DateList[{"Nov 2011", {"MonthName", " ", "Year"}}]` doesn't work (try it), even though `StringMatchQ["Nov 2011", DatePattern[{"MonthName", " ", "Year"}]]` gives `True`.  I suspect a bug.

Comment: Related (but not an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719842/import-data-from-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `DateFunction` option to tell `DateListPlot` how to convert dates:

```
DateFunction -> (DateList[{#, {"MonthNameShort", "YearShort"}}] &)
```

(The parentheses are important.)

Comment: I was doing precisely the same but `DateList[{"Nov-11", {"MonthNameShort", "YearShort"}}]` gives me `DateString::str`!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a non-English locale on Windows (tried with Hungarian and US English, and it only worked with English)

Comment: These dates most likely reflect monthly closing prices. It would be good it you could specify that the `DateList` was for the close of the month rather than for the start. You can obviously make the changes to the `DateList` post conversion but would be nice if the options existed ...or maybe it does but I don't know it??

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch You could use `DatePlus` to move to the end of the month (perhaps with +1 month, -1 day).

Comment: @Brett that is what I currently do but was just making the observation that it would be nice if this could be done via some sort of option.

Comment: @Brett, note also the continued frustration with the slowness of date and time functions: http://www.wheels.org/monkeywrench/?p=453

Answer (score 6):

Why not to use WolframAlpha[...] function - it imports native to Mathematica format and goes up to current dates:

```
    timeseries = WolframAlpha["msft close Jan 1, 2010 to Jan 21 2011",
{{"DateRangeSpecified:Close:FinancialData", 1}, "TimeSeriesData"}];
DateListPlot[timeseries]
```

[image]

That was just an example of input. I am not sure what kind of data you need exactly, but you can get a lot of them via WolframAlpha function. Read this:

1) [WolframAlpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WolframAlpha.html)
2) [Data Formats in Wolfram|Alpha](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DataFormatsInWolframAlpha.html)

Comment: @Vitaly, Thank you very much for your answer. I shall try this as soon as I am back to work !

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function to convert those date strings to a format Mathematica can handle better:

```
dateConv = With[{s = StringSplit[#, "-"]}, {DateList[{s[[2]], "YearShort"}][[1]],
     DateList[s[[1]]][[2]]}] &
```

You can try

```
DateListPlot[data, DateFunction -> dateConv]
```

---

**EDIT:** Originally I tried `DateList[{"Nov-11", {"MonthNameShort", "YearShort"}}]` but this tells me `String "Nov-
 11" cannot be interpreted as a date in format {"MonthNameShort", 
    "YearShort"}.`.  Perhaps a bug?

Comment: It works for me as it is, but I normally use DateList[{"Nov-11", {"MonthNameShort", "-", "YearShort"}}] and it always works.

Comment: @b.gatessucks It does not work here in Mma 8.0.4 (Windows), separator specified or not.  I did try the separator form as well before I decided to make the workaround-function from my answer.

Comment: I confirm it works with Mma 8.0.4 both on Windows 7 and Linux 64 bit.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks!  It must either be XP specific or my Mma installation is broken then

Comment: @b.gatessucks I figured it out: on Windows it only works if I set the locale to US English.